# How to stay on a Bootstrap PopUp form after validation?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm actually developing a Web site where you can register yourself from a form.

I've create a code in *PHP* for managing the errors which could happen (wrong number, mail...)

Here is my problem : When I send the form, I cant manage to stay on it to overwrite the form with the errors encounters (if there are some).

I'm using Bootstrap form the form and I have absolutely no clue of how to do that.

### This is the my **HTML**

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="ins" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form id="FormIns" action="Index.php" method="post">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="text-center">Inscription</h4>
                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" id="lname" placeholder="Nom" maxlength="25">
                              </div>
                          </div><br/>

                          <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="fname" placeholder="Prénom" maxlength="25">
                              </div>
                          </div><br/>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nid" id="nidentifiant" placeholder="Identifiant" maxlength="25">
                                </div>
                            </div><br/>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="npass" id="npassword" placeholder="Mot de Passe" maxlength="25">
                                </div>
                            </div><br/>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cnpass" id="cnpassword" placeholder="Confirmer Mot de Passe" maxlength="25">
                                </div>
                            </div><br/>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                    <input type="mail" class="form-control" name="mail" id="mail" placeholder="Adresse Email" maxlength="25">
                                </div>
                            </div><br/>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Numéro de Téléphone" maxlength="25">
                                </div>
                            </div><br/>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Inscription" name="log">
                                <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Annuler</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should add labels to your form fields. These help with the page as well as give a good entry point for error messages.

A simple approach would be to set the form-action to the form page, and put validation errors in an associative array with values like
`$errors['name'] = "Name did not match";` and so on and so forth.

Then you add a `<span>` at the end of the label like (roughly) this:

```
<span>
  <?php echo (isset($errors['name'])) ? $errors['name'] : "";?>
</span>
</label>
```

This would make PHP evaluate the errors and put them into the label so they can be easily connected to the field.

Lastly, to continue, you add a redirect to the next page, if the validation is successful, so create a `redirect` function and send the validated data to the next page.

€: for good effects, you can use php to append the `alert` or `warning` class to the corresponding `form-control` groups or `input`s.

Comment: I'm already doing all of it; actually the form is a PopUp so he is on the page and redirect to the page.
The main problem is that it close itself when the submit button is pressed.

Comment: Try setting a boolean value if any errors are present, and then try this:

    `<?php
    $class = ($errorsPresent) ? 'class="modal show"' : 'class="modal  fade"';
    ?>
    <div <?php echo $class ?> id="ins" ...>` 

This is a very crude approach, you'd do better with a check in JavaScript or setting the form to a seperate page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a script to check that the values are right, the first thing you have to do is stop the form action.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#FormIns").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
// your code to check the form goes here

//once you finished and everything is right then:
$( "#FormIns" ).submit();
  });

</script>
```